# SSIS 2008: How to merge two data sources (one row, one column) into one row (two columns)

Tags: ssis

In the below SSIS data flow task I have two Salesforce.com sources

- The top one returns one row, one column named is_current
- The top bottom returns one row, one column named is_deleted

Where the question mark is, what SSIS component do I use to transform the above into one row with columns is_current and is_deleted?

The Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL) doesn't support UNION ALL or independent subqueries, otherwise I'd just handle both in SQL in the source task. [image]

Answer (score 0):

[Merge Join Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141775(v=sql.100).aspx) should be used here. However you need join keys to perform join. In this case you can add artificial columns in each flow with same values (`1` for example) by using [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069(v=sql.100).aspx) and use them as join keys. More detailed expalnation you can find here : http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2010/09/performing-cross-join-cartesian-product.html